# How to create a swap function in Prolog with a temp variable?

Tags: prolog, swap

I need to create a program to swap two values with a temporary variable in prolog as a part of my advanced programming class. This is my first time using the language, and from what I've seen, a temporary variable isn't even necessary. I have no idea how to go about this. Please help.

Comment: Could you specify what to swap? Once your variable is unificated, it can not change content, so you might want to swap elements in a tuple or list?

Comment: This is a very strange request. As you write yourself, this is very unnecessary in Prolog. If you want to get a useful answer, you might need to divulge more information about the task you have been given. There is such a thing as overwriting the value of a Prolog variable but this is definitely deep into "dirty hacks" territory :-) technically you can do it but why?

Comment: @TA_intern "overwriting the value of a Prolog variable ... technically you can do" how? I don't know any. :) what did you have in mind, please?

Comment: @WillNess depends on the Prolog implementation. SWI-Prolog for example has setarg/3, nb_setarg/3, anything in [global variables](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar); there is also of course assert/retract and friends. Maybe you can ask a question or search on SO? ;-)

Comment: @TA_intern thanks for the clarifications. "Prolog variable" is usually taken to mean "Prolog logical variable".

Comment: @WillNess setarg/3 and nb_setarg/3 will both in effect change the "content" of a term bound to a "Prolog logical variable". Try: `?- X = a(foo), writeln(X), setarg(1, X, bar), writeln(X).`

Comment: @TA_intern great, thanks.

Comment: @TA_intern Actually, the binding goes the other way: The Prolog variable (really, the variable name but Prolog terminology is rather fluid & full of historical phenomena) _is bound to_ a term. As in "`X` is bound to 3", "`X` is bound to the same term as is `Y`" and "`X` is unbound and so is `Y` but both designate the same 'hole' (and so `X` == `Y`)" ("hole" is somewhat my adopted terminology). But Will knows all of that...

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
% swap(?Pair,?Pair)
swap([A,B],[B,A]).
```

Or, with "two values" represented as pair `A-B`

```
% swap(?Pair,?Pair)
swap(A-B,B-A).
```

And so:

```
?- swap(1-2,X).
X = 2-1.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand how this works now! You're a lifesaver

Comment: @Joe This still does not use a temporary variable. This is more akin to reversing a list than swapping anything (and sorry David Tonhofer but I cannot bring myself admit that this is a useful answer without more details from OP). Enjoy responsibly.

Comment: @TA_intern Such is life at Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hehe I am still new at this. Contributing to SO sounds like a good idea but I am already starting to have my doubts.